# Modify DOM in content-script as a replacement for the non-ability to trigger pop-ups programmatically?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on an extension that's supposed to use the content of the page to determine whether to show an interface to the user.

The ways to show an interface, if I'm correct, are using a browser action or a page action.

And neither can be triggered programmatically. But content scripts could be written to inject an equivalent GUI into the webpage.

So, **does it make sense to modify the DOM using content-scripts to display an interface as a substitute for page action**? It seems like an obvious work around to me, and I'm sure there are good reasons to not let page actions be triggered programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Well, modifying DOM must be done by only Content Scripts, as that is the reason they exist.

Want to fetch any data from current page, alter anything in the page, add new UI in the page - whatever, content script will help you do that.

It has nothing to do with Page script Or Browser Script.

YES, you can not programatically trigger page/browser action. It has to be done by explicit clicking.

But if you want to open a UI by clicking a chrome extension, then there is a popup js for that.